# Creating a 'Break' between Unions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm still very new to Microsoft SQL, so I'm just trying to figure a few things out.
Apologies if I've done something wrong; posting in the wrong area, not posting this correctly, ect.

**Query:**

```
SELECT TOP 10 YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 'Year', MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 'Index', 'January 2014' 'Month', U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName 'Full Name', A.EffectedUserName 'Username', US.RoleName 'Role Name', COUNT(*) 'Amount'
FROM Audits A, Users U, UserSlot US
WHERE A.EffectedUserName = U.UserName
AND U.UserName = US.UserName
AND A.EventName = 'UserLogin'
AND A.EffectedUserName not in ('Admin')
AND A.DateTime between '2014/01/01' and '2014/02/01'
GROUP BY YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName, US.RoleName, A.EffectedUserName

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 10 YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 'Year', MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 'Index', 'February 2014' 'Month', U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName 'Full Name', A.EffectedUserName 'Username', US.RoleName 'Role Name', COUNT(*) 'Amount'
FROM Audits A, Users U, UserSlot US
WHERE A.EffectedUserName = U.UserName
AND U.UserName = US.UserName
AND A.EventName = 'UserLogin'
AND A.EffectedUserName not in ('Admin')
AND A.DateTime between '2014/02/01' and '2014/03/01'
GROUP BY YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName, US.RoleName, A.EffectedUserName

ORDER BY YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), [Amount] Desc
```

This is about 1/6 of the entire Query. I'd like to have a '*Break*' between every Month. Therefore there'd be a *gap*, or something, which splits every month from each other.
Like:

```
- January 2014
- January 2014
- January 2014

- February 2014
- February 2014
- February 2014

- March 2014
- March 2014
- March 2014
```

The *gap* being the '*Break*' in the UNION ALL.

I feel like I didn't ask the question very well, but I'm not too sure how else to word it. Thank you! :)

Comment: which RDBM are you using ?MSSQL?MySql?or else?

Comment: No, you can't do this in the query itself. Insert the break in whatever front end (web page or application) you're using to display the data.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am talking about MSSQL

Comment: @ShelimShahid: Why are you not adding a extra column for every month as you want to seprate the every month result

Comment: @KhurramAli: I'm sorry, I thought I am doing what you're talking about? The Month column is the third column

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something this

```
SELECT TOP 10 YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 
'Year', MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 
'Index', 'January 2014' 'Month', U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName 'Full 
 Name', A.EffectedUserName 'Username', US.RoleName 'Role Name', COUNT(*) 'Amount',
'January' Month
    FROM Audits A, Users U, UserSlot US
    WHERE A.EffectedUserName = U.UserName
    AND U.UserName = US.UserName
    AND A.EventName = 'UserLogin'
    AND A.EffectedUserName not in ('Admin')
    AND A.DateTime between '2014/01/01' and '2014/02/01'
    GROUP BY YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), 
    MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))),
    U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName, US.RoleName, A.EffectedUserName

    UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 10 YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 
'Year', MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 
'Index', 'January 2014' 'Month', U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName 'Full 
 Name', A.EffectedUserName 'Username', US.RoleName 'Role Name', COUNT(*) 'Amount',
'February' Month
    FROM Audits A, Users U, UserSlot US
    WHERE A.EffectedUserName = U.UserName
    AND U.UserName = US.UserName
    AND A.EventName = 'UserLogin'
    AND A.EffectedUserName not in ('Admin')
    AND A.DateTime between '2014/02/01' and '2014/03/01'
    GROUP BY YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), 
    MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))),
    U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName, US.RoleName, A.EffectedUserName
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just gives me an extra column. I need an extra row to determine when a new Month starts.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this is what you are looking. You can just add empty row to create gap. It's better to do on front end rather than back end.

```
SELECT TOP 10 YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 'Year', MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 'Index', 'January 2014' 'Month', U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName 'Full Name', A.EffectedUserName 'Username', US.RoleName 'Role Name', COUNT(*) 'Amount'
    FROM Audits A, Users U, UserSlot US
    WHERE A.EffectedUserName = U.UserName
    AND U.UserName = US.UserName
    AND A.EventName = 'UserLogin'
    AND A.EffectedUserName not in ('Admin')
    AND A.DateTime between '2014/01/01' and '2014/02/01'
    GROUP BY YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName, US.RoleName, A.EffectedUserName

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null AS Year , null AS Index, null AS  Month, null AS Full Name, null AS Username,    null AS [Role Name], null AS Amount 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP 10 YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 'Year', MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))) 'Index', 'February 2014' 'Month', U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName 'Full Name', A.EffectedUserName 'Username', US.RoleName 'Role Name', COUNT(*) 'Amount'
    FROM Audits A, Users U, UserSlot US
    WHERE A.EffectedUserName = U.UserName
    AND U.UserName = US.UserName
    AND A.EventName = 'UserLogin'
    AND A.EffectedUserName not in ('Admin')
    AND A.DateTime between '2014/02/01' and '2014/03/01'
    GROUP BY YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName, US.RoleName, A.EffectedUserName

    ORDER BY YEAR(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), MONTH(CONVERT(Date, FORMAT(CONVERT(Date, A.DateTime), 'Y'))), [Amount] Desc
```

Comment: I think the question is asking for a gap that will separate each month of results

Comment: That's quite a neat thing to know, but unless I can Order that after every Month ending, I don't see it being in any use unfortunately (I don't think that's possible anyway). Besides, I think if I had multiple rows full of NULL's, it'd look odd to say the least.

What I need is something to determine when a new Month starts. So after January ends, there'll be a gap before February starts.

I don't know if this is possible at all (although what you suggested with the NULL's does give me a little hope).